# Does the expect command work after an su is executed in the script?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, sudo, su

Does the expect command work after an su is executed in the script?

Does expect work by emulating the feeding of key strokes to the terminal?

Comment: I answered, but @Mat is right. You could have proven it to yourself in less time than it took to write the question.

Comment: I only consider functionality to be genuine if it is part of the design specification. Just because something works does not mean it will always work. I don't like 'features'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, although the second bit ("emulating ... key strokes") is an oversimplification.